# Fully round SVG circle in Chrome? Bug workaround

Tags: google-chrome, svg

There's currently a bug in Chrome giving SVG circles edges, making them look like [stop signs](https://www.google.se/search?q=stop%20sign).

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395474

**Does anybody know of a temporary workaround?**

Use case - pie timer animation: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/c62qmq1a/

```
<div class="svg_wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 425">
      <path d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,150 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,-150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="110"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you draw with the shape instead of the stroke as in http://jsfiddle.net/7m522sm2/ ?

Comment: That looks pretty smooth! But unfortunately it seems to break the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/c62qmq1a/

Comment: Try two circles like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/pphf7tn3/). I'd used a different color to show the inner circle is smooth. Probably need 3 circles to make inner and outer circle smooth

Comment: Still not round @AlvinK.

Comment: @Duopixel still there?

Comment: @MarkBoulder: Which version of Chrome are you using? The updated [3 path version](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/pphf7tn3/2/). Fat strokes look like stop signs, thin strokes does not.

Comment: @AlvinK. Hi, I'm on Chrome 36. You're right, thin strokes look fine. So what should we do? Is there a way to make http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/c62qmq1a/ fully round or would we have to wait for that Chrome bug to be fixed?

Comment: Out of our control, have to wait this one out. Wondering if it would affect SVG font glyphs too.