# It is possible to obtain a perfect svg circle from parts?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, snap.svg

I've got 4 arcs of a circle which are generated using SnapSVG.js
The problem is that between the upper arcs the gap is higher than the gap of lower arcs
So my question is can I fix the gap between arcs and obtain a perfect circle using only CSS to  cosistency with resize?

This is a raw JS [I intend to clean it a bit]
http://jsfiddle.net/LtLafp2r/

```
var canvasSize = 200,
    centre = canvasSize/2,
    radius = canvasSize*0.8/2,
    s = Snap('#svg'),
    path = "",
    arc = s.path(path),    
    startY = centre-radius;

var d = 0;
var dr =0;

 radians = Math.PI*(dr)/180,
            endx = centre + radius*Math.cos(radians),
            endy = centre + radius * Math.sin(radians),
            largeArc = d>180 ? 1 : 0;  

var s = Snap("#svg");
// Lets create big circle in the middle:

path = "M"+centre+","+startY+" A"+radius+","+radius+" 0 "+largeArc+",1 "+endx+","+endy;

var arc = s.path(path);
// By default its black, lets change its attributes
 arc.attr({
          stroke: '#3da08d',
          fill: 'none',
          strokeWidth: 25
        });
```

Comment: Draw 4 circles, clip at each quadrant. Merging them would recreate the circle. Bound it with a <div> and use [CSS to resize SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279031/on-click-make-svg-resizable/25295895#25295895) . I'm not a fan of drawing circles using arc path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but using this CSS does a perfect circle with your arcs :

```
svg{position:fixed;}
#svg3{left:-72px; top:88px;}
#svg4{left:88px; top:88px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtLafp2r/3/

Ps: there is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102411) in rendering path arcs in Chrome : [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319325/fully-round-svg-circle-in-chrome-bug-workaround)

Comment: Note: on IE9 & FF, there are visible gaps between arcs, Chrome is OK.

Comment: @AlvinK. You're right, I didn't noticed it this morning. But I guess it's an odd bug, since rescaling the panels from jsfiddle seems to change this behaviour, at least on FF. Maybe someone has a clue on how to prevent this?