# Resizing SVG animation while keeping it centered in its container

Tags: css, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to center the `<path>` animation horizontally and vertically (after having scaled it down with `transform="scale(0.5))` while keeping the `<svg>` at 100% width and height of its container. I'm using [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/).

As you can see below, the `<svg>` is fine but the `<path>` is all crammed up in the upper left corner.

```js
var s = Snap("#me");


var myPath = s.select("#mypath");

function reset( el ) {
    el.stop();
    el.attr({ "stroke-dashoffset": 125 });
};

function startAnim( el ) {
    el.animate( { "stroke-dashoffset": 600 }, 1000 );
};

reset( myPath );

s.mouseover( function() {
  startAnim( myPath );
} );

s.mouseout( function() {
  reset( myPath );
} );
```

```css
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#me { 
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#mypath { 
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tedbeer.net/lib/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <div class="pie">
        <svg id="me" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
        <!--<svg id="me" viewBox="0 0 350 350" width="100" height="100">-->
            <path id="mypath" d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75, 75 0 1, 0 0, 150 a 75, 75 0 1, 0 0, -150" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000" transform="scale(0.5)">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you give the scale a transform around its center ?

Comment: Is this related to the `element.getBBox()` you mentioned earlier?

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: I was wondering if you did something like myPath.transform('s0.5,0.5,175,175'); http://jsfiddle.net/poyt9qew/ it depends really if you wanted to use markup or snap or whatever

Comment: That seems to do the trick quite nicely.. thanks man!!

Comment: Edited answer to make more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to amend the transform via Snap you would do it very slightly different.

The end result is probably the same to the browser as mefs solution, as it will end up having a similar matrix on the element itself, its really down to whats the most convenient.

You can specify a center point for the scaling, just add it after the scale x & y parameters.

```
myPath.transform('s0.5,0.5,175,175');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poyt9qew)

Edit: Actually I'm an idiot, its even more simple. I just remembered that Snap automatically uses the center of an object on transform strings if not specified. So in fact you can reduce it to this..

```
myPath.transform('s0.5');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poyt9qew/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The position of your object is affected by the scaling transform. Add a translation in order to move the object to the correct position, right after `scale`:

```
transform="scale(0.5)translate(175,175)"
```

updated snippet:

```js
var s = Snap("#me");


var myPath = s.select("#mypath");

function reset( el ) {
    el.stop();
    el.attr({ "stroke-dashoffset": 125 });
};

function startAnim( el ) {
    el.animate( { "stroke-dashoffset": 600 }, 1000 );
};

reset( myPath );

s.mouseover( function() {
  startAnim( myPath );
} );

s.mouseout( function() {
  reset( myPath );
} );
```

```css
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#me { 
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#mypath { 
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tedbeer.net/lib/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <div class="pie">
        <svg id="me" viewBox="0 0 350 350">
        <!--<svg id="me" viewBox="0 0 350 350" width="100" height="100">-->
            <path id="mypath" d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75, 75 0 1, 0 0, 150 a 75, 75 0 1, 0 0, -150" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000" transform="scale(0.5)translate(175,175)">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: possible other options based on the question in your comment:

**option 1**
If you do not want to have the translate at all, You can **change the `viewBox` coordinates**, this way:

```
<svg id="me" viewBox="-75 -75 350 350" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Please note that I haven't taken the time to calculate the exact ones that would be relevant to you, but you get the idea. You should adapt the four values so that they match to the viewport you want to obtain.

**option 2**

do some math to replace your current path coordinates by the ones for an object twice smaller, so that you don't need the scale transform anymore.

Comment: Any chance you could think of a way to scale without having to manually reposition things afterwards?

Comment: Cool, but then basically what this means is that there's no way to make the circle smaller without manually having to reposition / recalculate values afterwards?

Comment: The viewbox ccordinates option is something you should be able to apply all the time directly without calculation

Comment: looks to me like Ian's solution is the snap equivalent of the first one I have proposed.